# proof for binomial probabilty distribition

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Taking one of the example I have learned for binomial probability distribution

A fair die is thrown four times. calculate the probability of getting exactly  3 Twos ([source](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/binomial-distribution.html))

Answer can be obtained using the formula of binomial distribution as  4C3 (1/6)^3 (5/6)^(4-3). This is easy.

Can any one explain a combinatorics argument of getting the answer.

I see the denominator as total number of ways outcomes can come when dice is thrown 4 times as 6^4. How the numerator can be obtained using a similar argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of throwing three consecutive twos and *then* one other number is: $(\tfrac 1 6)^3(\tfrac 56)$.

To obtain the probability of throwing three twos and another number in no particular order, multiply by the permutation of 3 success and 1 failure.  That is ${^4\mathrm C_3} = \frac {4!}{3!1!}$

Final and correct answer: $${^4\mathrm C_3}(\tfrac 1 6)^3(\tfrac 56)$$

---

Alternatively: Counting equi-probable outcomes.

The total space contains $6^4$ ways to select any four outcomes.

The favoured outcomes are counted as the ${^4\mathrm C_3}$ ways to select dice to have $1^3$ successes (`2`) and the remaining $^1\mathrm C_1$ die have $5^1$ failures (not-`2`).   That gives:

$$\frac{{^4\mathrm C_3} \cdot 1^3\cdot 5^1}{6^4}$$

Comment: can I modify your statement as this, to make sure I am clear. select any three : 4C3 ways. then 1^3 as each of them can have (only two), rest in 1C1 way, then 5^1 (as each of this can have 1,3,4,5,6). therefore, favorable cases = 4C3 * 1^3 * 1C1 * 5^1  and denominator is always the total possible arrangements of 6^4, ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. @Kiran

Comment: @thx it clarified all the doubts

Answer (score 1):

there is 1 way of getting a 2 and 5 ways of getting a non-2

$\binom 4 3 $ is the number of ways of arranging 3 twos and 1 non-two

$$P = \binom 4 3 \frac{5}{6^6}= \binom 4 3 (\frac 16)^3(\frac 56)^1= \binom 4 3 (\frac 16)^3(\frac 56)^{(4-3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are 6^4 possible outcomes. How many good outcomes are there? You can have 2221, 2223, ... Therefore 4 possibilities to place the non-two and the non-two could be one of 5 numbers. Results in 5*4 = 20 possibilities. 20/6^4 = 4 * (1/6)^3 (5/6). I think you mean 4C3 = 4 instead of 6C3 (to place the non-two)?

Comment: yes, it is 4c3. thanks. edited